# See all entries/data in all tables in all tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am learning postgres. I have a lot of tables , is there a command for listing all the rows in all the tables if the table is non empty?

The tables are called test.test_* (where * is something else like test.test_abc , test.test_bcd etc). I can query the tables one by one in python and see if they control any data but is there any postgres command for this? Something like

`SELECT * FROM test.test_* IF pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('test.test_*')) >0;`

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. by docs [pg_relation_size](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html):

> Disk space used by the specified fork ('main', 'fsm', 'vm', or 'init')
>   of the specified table or index

disk space != number of rows. eg:

```
b=# create table empty (i int);
CREATE TABLE
b=# select pg_relation_size('public.empty');
 pg_relation_size
------------------
                0
(1 row)

b=# insert into empty select 1;
INSERT 0 1
b=# select pg_relation_size('public.empty');
 pg_relation_size
------------------
             8192
(1 row)

b=# delete from empty ;
DELETE 1

b=# select count(*) from empty;
 count
-------
     0
(1 row)

b=# select pg_relation_size('public.empty');
 pg_relation_size
------------------
             8192
(1 row)
```

2. `pg_size_pretty` returns text, so comparison should give you:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: text > integer

3. `IF` is plpgsql statement. for SQL you should use `CASE`, but in your statement you should use at all `WHERE` (`select * from tname WHERE number_of_rows > 0`)
4. Nevertheless, your question has a positive answer. It is doable. Same as you loop it in python, you can loop it inside `DO` plpgsql block.